# replace new linux kernel with make

Tags: linux, kernel, make

Nowdays, I have to compile linux kernel more and more...

So :

```
make /home/mohsen/K=kernel menuconfig 
make /home/mohsen/K=kernel 
make /home/mohsen/K=kernel modules_install install
```

Question is , When I run install target `make` command, I don't want to install new kernel and old kernel stay. Do you know a target for `make` command to replace my new kernel?

**UPDATE:**

Suppose , Once I did the following way:

```
    make /home/mohsen/K=kernel menuconfig 
    make /home/mohsen/K=kernel 
    make /home/mohsen/K=kernel modules_install install
```

Then I find out to add/remove to kernel , So do the following job:

```
make /home/mohsen/K=kernel menuconfig 
make /home/mohsen/K=kernel
```

For 3th command , When you use`kernel install`, This copy current kernel to *.old and install new kernel.
**I don't want to copy current kernel to *.old**

Comment: Could you clarify more of what you are asking? When you use `make` to compile the kernel, it will not replace your old kernel inside your `/boot` directory.

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `installkernel` command installs the kernel and there is no option to disable creating the `.old`. If you don't want it then you can use your own installation script and set the environment variable INSTALLKERNEL

```
INSTALLKERNEL
--------------------------------------------------
Install script called when using "make install".
The default name is "installkernel".

    The script will be called with the following arguments:
        $1 - kernel version
        $2 - kernel image file
        $3 - kernel map file
        $4 - default install path (use root directory if blank)
```

Without knowing what you are trying to do I'd humbly suggest you add `rm` of the old kernel to your installation steps rather than writing your own INSTALLKERNEL.